# http.createServer(app) v. http.Server(app)

Tags: node.js, express

On the socket.io web page, `Get Started: Chat application`, located here:

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

there is this code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

which could be rewritten a little more clearly like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
```

The socket.io example uses http.Server() to create a server.  Yet, the express docs for [app.listen()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen) show an example where the server is created using `http.createServer(app)`:

> **app.listen()**
>   Bind and listen for connections on the given host and port. This
>   method is identical to node's http.Server#listen().
>
> ```
> var express = require('express');  
> var app = express();  
> app.listen(3000);
> ```
>
> The app returned by express() is in fact a JavaScript Function,
>   designed to be passed to node's HTTP servers as a callback to handle
>   requests. This allows you to provide both HTTP and HTTPS versions of
>   your app with the same codebase easily, as the app does not inherit
>   from these (it is simply a callback):
>
> ```
> var express = require('express');
> var https = require('https');
> var http = require('http');
> var app = express();
>
> http.createServer(app).listen(80);
> https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
> ```
>
> The app.listen() method is a convenience method for the following (if
>   you wish to use HTTPS or provide both, use the technique above):
>
> ```
> app.listen = function(){
>   var server = http.createServer(this);
>   return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
> };
> ```

What's the difference between `http.createServer(app)` and `http.Server(app)`??  The http docs are no help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no difference. `http.createServer()` only does one thing: [it calls `http.Server()` internally and returns the resulting instance](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/523929c9272a53c9429616564a45f2af59670e47/lib/http.js#L1903-L1905).

Comment: Okay, I would prefer to type Server() instead of createServer(), so that's what I'll do.  Plus I'll save a function call.  Thanks.