# How to use HTTPS on Node.js using Express/Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, https, socket.io

Im trying to run my node server with https. I'm using express and socket.io.

This is my code for https:

```
var httpsPort = 443;
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(mykeypath');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(mycertificatepath');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var https = require('https').Server(credentials,app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

https.listen(httpsPort, function(){
logger.info('listening on *:' + httpsPort);
});


app.get('/initGame', function (req,res){

var slots = require('./slots.json', 'utf8');
var userObject = {
    address : req.connection.remoteAddress,
    userAgent : req.headers['user-agent']
};
db.getPlayedGames(userObject,function(playedGames){
    logger.debug(playedGames);
    if(typeof playedGames == 'undefined' ){
        playedGames=0;
    }else{
        playedGames = playedGames.games_played;
    }
    var spinsLeft = 10-playedGames;
    res.json({
        spinsLeft: spinsLeft,
        slots: slots
    });
  });
});
```

on my client its the following:

```
var myServer = "//" + document.domain + ":443";

$.get( myServer + "/initGame", function(data) {
    totalSpinsLeft = data.spinsLeft;
    $('#trysLeft').text(totalSpinsLeft);
    Seven.init(data.slots);
}).fail(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#spinner2').text('Fehler bitte neu laden!');
    },3000);

});
```

Right now im getting the following exception on my server:

`uncaughtException: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.`

EDIT: right now im getting

Bad Request

`Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It is hard to test your example without your key and cert files instead I am going to provide an example where I am using Express, socket.io, and https.

First I will create the key and cert files, so inside a directory run the following commands from your terminal:

The command below it is going to generate a file containing an RSA key.

```
$ openssl genrsa 1024 > file.pem
```

Here you will be asked to input data but you can leave blank pressing enter until the crs.pem is generated.

```
$ openssl req -new -key file.pem -out csr.pem
```

Then a file.crt file will be created containing an SSL certificate.

```
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey file.pem -out file.crt
```

---

So in my `app.js` file where I am setting and starting the server notice that I am using the files `file.pem` and `file.crt` generated in the last step:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};
var serverPort = 443;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');
  socket.emit('message', 'This is a message from the dark side.');
});

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

and then my `public/index.html` where I am consuming the server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>I am alive!!</h1>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
      var URL_SERVER = 'https://localhost:443';
      var socket = io.connect(URL_SERVER);

      socket.on('message', function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

then finally if you access from the browser at `https://localhost`, you will see an alert with a message that is coming from the websocket server.

Comment: worked for me too, thank you very much.   i notice you changed (dot)Server to (dot)createServer - any reason for this?  i changed mine too and it worked.

Comment: looks like there is no difference, look at this answer regarding your doubt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921117/http-createserverapp-v-http-serverapp

Comment: how to achieve this without the scary key warning? also, will this work with any port? or must I use 443? what if we have multiple services using socket.io and need diff ports? will there be cors issues?

Comment: Can I ask how you're making the require() function available on the client?

Comment: @DanL if you refer to `app.js` file, it is being run in the server side.

Comment: so `require` is automatically available on it.

Comment: @WilsonBalderrama I am referring to the code on public/index.html please thank you

Comment: well `<script src=...socket.io.js></script>` includes the lib so that in the next `<script>` used the socket.io.js is automatically available.

Comment: Thank you for this, What if I want it to work on http & https both??

Comment: Would like to add that now, second openssl command throws an error based upon the format of the .pem key outputted by the first openssl command.

Comment: please change the first command to `openssl genrsa 2048 > file.pem` to avoid the error `ERROR: error:140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small`

Comment: @Wilson do u have a client code for the same. can u post it plz.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to set it up with express:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var app = require('express')();
var https        = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./test_key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./test_cert.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./test_ca.crt'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
server.listen(8080);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {
    ...
});

app.get("/", function(request, response){
    ...
})
```

I hope that this will save someone's time.

Comment: Hi emonik, how do you get the test_key.key, test_cert.crt and test_cs.crt files?

Comment: I use lets encrypt as ssl.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson : use this for lets encrypt 

`var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem')
},app);`

Comment: Emonik, Thanks, but I still get this error? https://46.22.120.82:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. Im linking like this:<script src="https://46.22.120.82:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> And try to connect:var socket = io.connect('https://46.22.120.82:3000', {secure: true});

Comment: And in my server.js file I have this: var server = https.createServer({ key: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/kund-admin/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/manmade.se-key.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/kund-admin/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/manmade.se-chain.pem') },app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

Comment: I have this question here if you have the time to help me :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347766/how-to-use-https-with-letsencrypt-socket-io-and-node-js

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson I see you solved your problem :) , sorry it's just now that I saw your comment.