# SSL in socket.io with express: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, socket.io

I want to socket with socket.io through SSL. **I have read the other answers but nothing worked**

Here is my code:

```
var ssl_options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(my_key_path),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(my_cert_path)
};

var protocol = "https";

preparedApp = require(protocol).createServer(ssl_options,app);

var io = require('socket.io')(preparedApp);

preparedApp.listen(8080, function(){});
io.on('connection', function(socket){});
```

And here is the log of my ssl_options...

```
{ key: <Buffer 41 ...>,
 cert: <Buffer 4a ...> }
```

This errors with the error in the title `throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key.');`. Does anyone know what might be happening? None of the other solutions to this answer solved my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use PEM (RSA) format for your private key. Check if the private key is a base64 encoded, enclosed between "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

From the docs:

- key: A string or Buffer containing the private key of the server in PEM format
- cert : A string holding the PEM encoded certificate
- passphrase: A string of passphrase for the private key or pfx [optional default: null]

or

- pfx : A string or buffer holding the PFX or PKCS12 encoded private key, certificate and CA certificates

To convert a private key to RSA PEM: `openssl rsa -in <PATH TO KEY> -out key.pem -outform PEM`

To create a PKCS #12 bundle use `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -certfile ca.pem -out host.pfx`

-- ADDITION --

To ensure the cert is PEM encoded run `openssl x509 -in <PATH TO CERT> -out cert.pem -outform PEM`

Comment: Basically I turned my .key into a .pem using the command you told me to. Afterwards I changed my code to 
`var ssl_options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(my_pem_path), (is in .pem)
    cert : fs.readFileSync(my_cert_path) (is in .crt)
};`

but it still failed with the same errors. Any idea?

Comment: Try to encode the crt as pem. See addition of my answer.

Comment: dose the cert.pem file start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----?

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/mawi12345/836ef502529b8d6e6366 for an working example. Try to replace the key files in this example with your keys. Perhaps the error lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: any progress on testing with my example?

Comment: No, not at all... should I specify the domain somewhere in the nodejs code to validate my ssl credentials since they were first validated through domain name (as they normally are?)

Comment: The domain name gets checked by the client (browser). You don't have to specify it. Is your private key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: my problem should be before `var preparedApp = require(protocol).createServer(sslOptions, app);`. I stopped the server before that line and no ` Missing PFX or certificate + private key.` crashed

Comment: Any other idea? I even tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156884/how-to-use-https-on-node-js-using-express-socket-io by creating a new crt and pem but nothing worked...

Comment: What version of nodejs/io.js are you running? The problem is in the line `var preparedApp = require(protocol).createServer(sslOptions, app);`. The https server throws the exception since your `sslOptions` are somehow wrong. Does my example (gist) work without any changes?

Comment: I bumped this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212732/missing-pfx-or-certificate-private-key-in-https-socket-io since I still could not solve it... do you think you could give a helping hand? I have all those files in .pem but still it won't work. I'm using 1.3.7...