# 'Missing PFX or certificate + private key.' in https socket.io

Tags: ssl, socket.io

I have been having this problem for quite some time now but couldn't figure it out... Nothing I try really works at all. From conversions of the ssl files into many different formats and checking folder permissions nothing worked (or, to be more explicit, it all is as it should be to work). Does anyone know what could be off? Thank you very much for your help, I'm getting to the desperate side at this point...

**Could this be version related?** How could I check if that's the case?

Here is my code:

```
var ssl_options = {
    pfx : fs.readFileSync(my_pfx_path),
    passphrase: 'password'
};

//OR

var ssl_options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(my_key_path),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(my_cert_path)
};

var protocol = "https";

preparedApp = require(protocol).createServer(ssl_options,app);

var io = require('socket.io')(preparedApp);

preparedApp.listen(8080, function(){});
io.on('connection', function(socket){});
```

And here is the log of my ssl_options...

```
{ key: <Buffer 41 ...>,
 cert: <Buffer 4a ...> }
```

This errors with the error in the title `throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key.');`.

Full trace log:

```
 Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.
at Server (tls.js:1127:11)
at new Server (https.js:35:14)
at Object.Server (https.js:29:41)
at Object.<anonymous> (/nginx/script.js:477:34)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Could someone give me a helping hand? tyvm...

**I'm using socket.io version 1.3.7**
The cert is working with regular https in the browser / non-socket.io. The files are correct so I really don't know why this should be happening

Comment: Without more details, it looks like my_key_path is not correct.  Make sure it is relative to the directory that your application is running from.

Comment: @gary nope, it does not throw any errors of "file does not exist" as it does when I put a wrong file on purpose. I'm using absolute paths in both of them

Comment: @Gary I'm now positive that the path is correct, which details do you need me to provide to assume what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using the first or second version of ssl_options in your post?  Are you sure that you are using the correct cert and key?

Comment: @gary yes I am... I don't really know why this should be happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a broken if clause in my code that returned protocol to "http" and caused an error when trying to fetch the ssl info...