# Node, socket.io with SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I have a problem with node.js, socket.io and a new SSL certificate i implemented. Tried a lot of solutions here on stackoverflow already but i just can't get it working. Would love to have some custom made help for my situation and hopefully help others.

Without SSL the situation is like this:

**On my node.js script**

```js
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

**In my html page**

```js
var socket = io('http://mywebsite.com:8080');
```

This is working fine but when i throw a SSL certificate in the mix it goes wrong. I tried some solutions like below:

```js
var https = require('https'),
    fs =    require('fs');

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/server.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

```js
var io = io('https://mywebsite.com', { secure: true });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31165649/2036977

Comment: Tried the solution from Wilson and from emonik. Both did not give me a connection :(

Comment: Try listening on port 443. Also use full URL in the connection since your certificate is for your full domain. You might need to use sudo to TEST the connection. I advice you to use a reverse proxy like nginx to handle your secured connection and reroute it on the nginx to your app on port 8080.

Comment: @Riddell Did you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);` is not correct. It should be `var io = require('socket.io')(app);` since the require from socket io gives back a function (and you need to pass the server into it).

Comment: Changed to:
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

html now:
var socket = io('https://website:8080');

Still no connection :(