# Socket.IO SSL connection error not using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my Socket.IO server, but the connection couldn't be made. It works without HTTPS. I created the pem and crt file with `openssl` command, I also have opened port `3300` through Firewall.

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('file.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);
io.listen(app); 
app.listen('3300');
```

Calling the server/url.

```
io('https://example.com:3300');
```

NodeJS is just as a backend, I'm not using express or anything on there.

Comment: What is being logged by the client/browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using,

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3300', {secure: true})
```

**UPDATE**

Try following the instructions in

[How to use HTTPS on Node.js using Express/Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156884/how-to-use-https-on-node-js-using-express-socket-io)

Comment: did you try the Update ?