# socket.io - polling-xhr.js:264 GET error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, long-polling

I've been working on my chat application on my localhost machine (which works fine), but when I'm trying to host it on [Github](https://github.com/) or [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/), I get this error `polling-xhr.js:264` on both hosts (both hosts have an `https` connection). I am using [cfenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv) to parse Cloud Foundry-provided environment variables. Here is a picture of the error in question:

[image: error]

It'll keep going like that...

Here is a look at my code:

> server.js

```
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function(){
    console.log("Server starting on " + appEnv.url);
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

... // rest of socket.io code
```

> index.html

```
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
...
```

> socketService.js ([btford's socket.io extension](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io))

```
app.factory('socket', function(socketFactory){
    return socketFactory();
});
```

I've tried various code suggested here on *StackOverflow*, but I can't seem to get it right. My code works very well with `localhost`, but it doesn't work when there is an *actual* server such as one mentioned above.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> both hosts have an https connection

But you have in your server code:

```
require('http');
```

Try using the `https` module instead of `http`. That might explain why the app only works in localhost. Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

You should also verify that your server is listening on port 443 instead of 80

Comment: I did try https on port 443 but no go. I did also try a solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156884/how-to-use-https-on-node-js-using-express-socket-io
By the way, I am using btford's socket.io extension. Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out from a good friend that the servers I was hosting on does not support `node.js` and that's why it didn't work. When my friend hosted his server with it installed, it worked very nice.

Comment: I've been trying to do so. I thought I might have found a work around because I have GoDaddy and through SSH and PuTTY installed node.js as well as npm, nvm, socket.io and whatever is normal for this procedure. My code works for localhost but once I transfer and try to use on GoDaddy, it doesn't work. Even though I have node.js, are you saying that GoDaddy still may not support it? -- I can run the code and everything as well as print out "Listening on this port" from the .js file but sadly can't connect the socket properly.