# WebRTC signaling server using Express & 'websocket' packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, webrtc

I am working with the following code from Rob Manson's *Getting Started with WebRTC*. It's implemented using Node.js. The code starts a real-time video call, and I have got it running as expected between 2 tabs in a web browser. I am simply trying to modify this so that it uses Express instead of the 'http' package.

The problem I am having is that there is no video getting displayed in my version. The 'Caller' works as expected, but then the 'Callee' stalls at the "One moment please...connecting your call..." message. There are no errors detected in the browser console or my terminal, and having spent a day trying to resolve the issue I still have little idea where I am going wrong.

Here is the original signalling server file:

```
// useful libs
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var websocket = require("websocket").server;

// general variables
var port = 8000;
var webrtc_clients = [];
var webrtc_discussions = {};

// web server functions
var http_server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      var matches = undefined;
      if (matches = request.url.match("^/images/(.*)")) {
            var path = process.cwd()+"/images/"+matches[1];

            fs.readFile(path, function(error, data) {
              if (error) {
                      log_error(error);
              } else {
                      response.end(data);
              }
            });
      } else {
          response.end(page);
      }
});

http_server.listen(port, function() {
        log_comment("server listening (port "+port+")");
});

var page = undefined;
fs.readFile("basic_video_call.html", function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
          log_error(error);
      } else {
          page = data;
      }
});

// web socket functions
var websocket_server = new websocket({
  httpServer: http_server
});
websocket_server.on("request", function(request) {

  log_comment("new request ("+request.origin+")");

  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  log_comment("new connection ("+connection.remoteAddress+")");

  webrtc_clients.push(connection);
  connection.id = webrtc_clients.length-1;

  connection.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.type === "utf8") {
      log_comment("got message "+message.utf8Data);

          var signal = undefined;
          try { signal = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data); } catch(e) { };

          if (signal) {
            if (signal.type === "join" && signal.token !== undefined) {
                  try {
                        if (webrtc_discussions[signal.token] === undefined) {
                                webrtc_discussions[signal.token] = {};
                        }
                  } catch(e) { };
                  try {
                      webrtc_discussions[signal.token][connection.id] = true;
                  } catch(e) { };
            } else if (signal.token !== undefined) {
                  try {
                        Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[signal.token]).forEach(function(id) {
                              if (id != connection.id) {
                                      webrtc_clients[id].send(message.utf8Data, log_error);
                              }
                        });
                  } catch(e) { };
            } else {
                log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
            }
          } else {
                  log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
          }
    }
  });

  connection.on("close", function(connection) {
        log_comment("connection closed ("+connection.remoteAddress+")"); 

        Object.keys(webrtc_discussions).forEach(function(token) {
              Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[token]).forEach(function(id) {
                if (id === connection.id) {
                    delete webrtc_discussions[token][id];
                }
              });
        });
  });
});

// utility functions
function log_error(error) {
  if (error !== "Connection closed" && error !== undefined) {
    log_comment("ERROR: "+error);
  }
}
function log_comment(comment) {
  console.log((new Date())+" "+comment);
}
```

And here is my modified file. Just the first bit has been changed:

```
// useful libs
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var websocket = require("websocket").server;
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// general variables
var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 8000;
var webrtc_clients = [];
var webrtc_discussions = {};

var expressApp = express();

expressApp.use(morgan('dev'));

var myRouter = express.Router();

myRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

// web server functions
myRouter.route('/').all(function(request,response,next) {
  var matches = undefined;
  if (matches = request.url.match("^/images/(.*)")) {
    var path = process.cwd() +"/images/"+matches[1];

    debugger;
    console.log("PATH: " + path);

    fs.readFile(path, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        log_error(error);
      } else {
        response.end(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    response.end(page);
  }
});
//////////////////////


expressApp.use('/',myRouter);

expressApp.listen(port, hostname, function(){
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

/////////////////////// **I CHANGED NOTHING BELOW HERE** ////////////

var page = undefined;
fs.readFile("basic_video_call.html", function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    log_error(error);
  } else {
    page = data;
  }
});



// web socket functions
var websocket_server = new websocket({
  httpServer: expressApp
});

websocket_server.on("request", function(request) {


  log_comment("new request ("+request.origin+")");

  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  log_comment("new connection ("+connection.remoteAddress+")");

  webrtc_clients.push(connection);
  connection.id = webrtc_clients.length-1;

  connection.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.type === "utf8") {
      log_comment("got message "+message.utf8Data);

      var signal = undefined;
      try { signal = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data); } catch(e) { };
      if (signal) {
        if (signal.type === "join" && signal.token !== undefined) {
          try {
            if (webrtc_discussions[signal.token] === undefined) {
              webrtc_discussions[signal.token] = {};
            }
          } catch(e) { };
          try {
            webrtc_discussions[signal.token][connection.id] = true;
          } catch(e) { };
        } else if (signal.token !== undefined) {
          try {
            Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[signal.token]).forEach(function(id) {
              if (id != connection.id) {
                webrtc_clients[id].send(message.utf8Data, log_error);
              }
            });
          } catch(e) { };
        } else {
          log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
        }
      } else {
        log_comment("invalid signal: "+message.utf8Data);
      }
    }
  });

  connection.on("close", function(connection) {
    log_comment("connection closed ("+connection.remoteAddress+")");    
    Object.keys(webrtc_discussions).forEach(function(token) {
      Object.keys(webrtc_discussions[token]).forEach(function(id) {
        if (id === connection.id) {
          delete webrtc_discussions[token][id];
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

// utility functions
function log_error(error) {
  if (error !== "Connection closed" && error !== undefined) {
    log_comment("ERROR: "+error);
  }
}
function log_comment(comment) {
  console.log((new Date())+" "+comment);
}
```

Also, here is the code that handles the WebRTC call, which I haven't changed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
/*

  webrtc_polyfill.js by Rob Manson
  NOTE: Based on adapter.js by Adam Barth

  The MIT License

  Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Rob Manson, http://buildAR.com. All rights reserved.

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  THE SOFTWARE.

*/

var webrtc_capable = true;
var rtc_peer_connection = null;
var rtc_session_description = null;
var get_user_media = null;
var connect_stream_to_src = null;
var stun_server = "stun.l.google.com:19302";

if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // WebRTC 1.0 standard compliant browser
  rtc_peer_connection = RTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.getUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    // https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21606
    media_element.srcObject = media_stream;
    media_element.play();
  };
} else if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) { // early firefox webrtc implementation
  rtc_peer_connection = mozRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = mozRTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.mozGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.mozSrcObject = media_stream;
    media_element.play();
  };
  stun_server = "74.125.31.127:19302";
} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // early webkit webrtc implementation
  rtc_peer_connection = webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  rtc_session_description = RTCSessionDescription;
  get_user_media = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  connect_stream_to_src = function(media_stream, media_element) {
    media_element.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(media_stream);
  };
} else {
  alert("This browser does not support WebRTC - visit WebRTC.org for more info");
  webrtc_capable = false;
}
</script>
<script>
/*

  basic_video_call.js by Rob Manson

  The MIT License

  Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Rob Manson, http://buildAR.com. All rights reserved.

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  THE SOFTWARE.

*/

var call_token; // unique token for this call
var signaling_server; // signaling server for this call
var peer_connection; // peer connection object

function start() {
  // create the WebRTC peer connection object
  peer_connection = new rtc_peer_connection({ // RTCPeerConnection configuration 
    "iceServers": [ // information about ice servers
      { "url": "stun:"+stun_server }, // stun server info
    ]
  });

  // generic handler that sends any ice candidates to the other peer
  peer_connection.onicecandidate = function (ice_event) {
    if (ice_event.candidate) {
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type: "new_ice_candidate",
          candidate: ice_event.candidate ,
        })
      );
    }
  };

  // display remote video streams when they arrive using local <video> MediaElement
  peer_connection.onaddstream = function (event) {
    connect_stream_to_src(event.stream, document.getElementById("remote_video"));
    // hide placeholder and show remote video
    document.getElementById("loading_state").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("open_call_state").style.display = "block";
  };

  // setup stream from the local camera 
  setup_video();

  // setup generic connection to the signaling server using the WebSocket API
  signaling_server = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

  if (document.location.hash === "" || document.location.hash === undefined) { // you are the Caller

    // create the unique token for this call 
    var token = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    call_token = "#"+token;

    // set location.hash to the unique token for this call
    document.location.hash = token;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {
      // setup caller signal handler
      signaling_server.onmessage = caller_signal_handler;

      // tell the signaling server you have joined the call 
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Caller";
    document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "Ready for a call...ask your friend to visit:<br/><br/>"+document.location;

  } else { // you have a hash fragment so you must be the Callee 

    // get the unique token for this call from location.hash
    call_token = document.location.hash;

    signaling_server.onopen = function() {
      // setup caller signal handler
      signaling_server.onmessage = callee_signal_handler;

      // tell the signaling server you have joined the call 
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"join",
        })
      );

      // let the caller know you have arrived so they can start the call
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({ 
          token:call_token,
          type:"callee_arrived",
        })
      );
    }

    document.title = "You are the Callee";
    document.getElementById("loading_state").innerHTML = "One moment please...connecting your call...";
  }

}

/* functions used above are defined below */

// handler to process new descriptions
function new_description_created(description) {
  peer_connection.setLocalDescription(
    description, 
    function () {
      signaling_server.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          token:call_token,
          type:"new_description",
          sdp:description 
        })
      );
    }, 
    log_error
  );
}

// handle signals as a caller
function caller_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "callee_arrived") {
    peer_connection.createOffer(
      new_description_created, 
      log_error
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate)
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {
        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "answer") {
          // extend with your own custom answer handling here
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else {
    // extend with your own signal types here
  }
}

// handle signals as a callee
function callee_signal_handler(event) {
  var signal = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (signal.type === "new_ice_candidate") {
    peer_connection.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate)
    );
  } else if (signal.type === "new_description") {
    peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(
      new rtc_session_description(signal.sdp), 
      function () {
        if (peer_connection.remoteDescription.type == "offer") {
          peer_connection.createAnswer(new_description_created, log_error);
        }
      },
      log_error
    );
  } else {
    // extend with your own signal types here
  }
}

// setup stream from the local camera 
function setup_video() {
  get_user_media(
    { 
      "audio": true, // request access to local microphone
      "video": true  // request access to local camera
      //"video": {mandatory: {minHeight:8, maxHeight:8, minWidth:8, maxWidth:8}}
    }, 
    function (local_stream) { // success callback
      // display preview from the local camera & microphone using local <video> MediaElement
      connect_stream_to_src(local_stream, document.getElementById("local_video"));
      // add local camera stream to peer_connection ready to be sent to the remote peer
      peer_connection.addStream(local_stream);
    },
    log_error
  );
}

// generic error handler
function log_error(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

</script>
<style>
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Arial","Helvetica",sans-serif;
}
#loading_state {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#open_call_state {
  display: none;
}
#local_video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #333333;
}
#remote_video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  background: #999999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <div id="loading_state">
        loading...
    </div>

    <div id="open_call_state">
        <video id="remote_video"></video>
        <video id="local_video"></video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also open to solutions that don't use Express but that still support authentication in WebRTC. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I discovered the solution. It simply involved replacing this line:

```
expressApp.listen(port, hostname, function() {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
}
```

With this one:

```
var webServer = http.createServer(expressApp).listen(8000);
```

The reason this worked is somewhat explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921117/http-createserverapp-v-http-serverapp). Apologies for wasting anyone's time with a trivial problem.