# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. NextJS+socket.io+PM2

Tags: express, http, socket.io, next.js, pm2

This is my first experience with socket. My project stack: NextJS(v10), express, socket.io, socket.io-client, freeice

Everything works fine on localhost. The problem arose when I decided to test on a test server(started project with PM2).

**server.ts**

```
const nextApp = next({ dev: config.dev });
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', socket => console.log('connected')); // did not write the rest of the code here, because I don't even get the console.log
```

**on client side**

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const options = {
   'force_new_connection': true,
   reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
   timeout: 10000,
   transports: ['websocket']
};
const socket = io('http s://mysite.com:3000', options);
```

**what i get in a short time:**

> WebSocket connection to '' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

The first and probably the most banal question due to my inexperience is whether I should configure anything on the Amazon server itself (probably said nonsense) and whether it can somehow have an impact PM2?

Second, here ***const server = require('http').Server(app);***. It is problem?

I checked, I don't call close() anywhere, it happens here:
[image]

Thanks for any help

I found another small difference between a local test and a site test. I am getting two different objects. What is ***lt***?

```
const socket = io(connectionUrl, options);
console.log('socket: ', socket);
```

localhost:
[image]

on mysite.com:
[image]

Comment: For your second question check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921117/http-createserverapp-v-http-serverapp  and for your first question which socket.io-client version you are using ?

Comment: "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",

Comment: You probably need to past the full code to let other further investigate (or better create a github project to reproduce your problem). But if you just experience it you better not use https (as in your code pasted here)

Comment: I won't be able to put it on github in its entirety, it's an existing big project that I decided to add a video chat to. The strange thing is that it works locally (yarn dev - OK, build + PM2 start - OK too) 
Which suggests that it is here that some kind of nuance is hidden, I’ll check with the system administrator, maybe there are some nuances on the server itself, I’m not good at this (

Comment: But if it helps, I can post almost the complete server.ts code, and client page, that used socket